# Fourier Series of a NonSymmetric Function with different intervals

Tags: fourier-series, matlab

I've been working with Fourier Series last weeks and I haven't found a solution for the problem I'm doing. I have the following function

[Input function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk0eR.png)

It is defined as piecewise for the following intervals.

```
f(t) = sin(w*x) when 0  <= x <= Ts

f(t) = 0        when Ts <  x <= T
```

where `w= pi/Ts, T = 60/72 = 0.8333, and Ts= 2T/5 = 0.333 so, the intervals are [0,0.333] and (0.333,0.8333)`

I had found the fourier series in Matlab when the intervals are symmetricals , lets say [0,0.333] and (0.333,0.666] but when I try to do any function with nonsymmetrical intervals I'm not able to find the correct solution.

I give another example of what I'm trying to find.

Lets suppose I have a square signal with amplitude $\pi$.

I obtained this when doing a symmetrical interval.
[Sym Interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF8jV.png)

and this when non-symmetrical

[Non-Symmetrical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgoHV.png)

I'm using the regular equations of Fourier Series to find Ao, Ak and Bk.[4](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) considering that my input function is both even and odd I'm obtaining both coefficients Bk and Ak as well as Ao.

On matlab I'm obtaining my intervals by separated as follows:

```
T=60/72; %seconds 
time=linspace(0,T,200);

Ts=2*T/5;
w1=pi/Ts;
Input=sin(w1*(time)).*(time <= Ts);
plot(time,Input,'-b','LineWidth',4) %Input Function to use
hold on 
grid on

%% Fourier Series

syms t n x
k=15; %Number of Fourier Coefficients

f1=sin(w1*x);
f2=0;

lim_inf_1=0;
lim_sup_1=Ts;

lim_inf_2=Ts;
lim_sup_2=T;

Ao= (1/(lim_sup_1))*(double(int(f1,x,lim_inf_1,lim_sup_1))) + (1/(lim_sup_2))*double(int(f2,x,lim_inf_2,lim_sup_2))
A=(1/(lim_sup_1))*(int(f1.*cos(n*w1*x),x,lim_inf_1,lim_sup_1)) + (1/(lim_sup_2))*int(f2.*cos(n*w1*x),x,lim_inf_2,lim_sup_2);
B=(1/(lim_sup_1))*(int(f1.*sin(n*w1*x),x,lim_inf_1,lim_sup_1)) + (1/(lim_sup_2))*int(f2.*sin(n*w1*x),x,lim_inf_2,lim_sup_2);

time=linspace(-Ts,2.5*Ts,200);

for n=1:k
    Ak(n,1)= double(subs(A));
    Bk(n,1)= double(subs(B));
    SF(:,n)=Ak(n)*cos(n*w1*(time)) + Bk(n)*sin(n*w1*(time));
end
Ak
Bk
SignalFourier = sum(SF,2) + Ao/2;

plot(time,SignalFourier,'-g','LineWidth',2)
```

I hope there is enough information so you can understand my problem, thanks everyone in advance for reading and spending your time on helping me.

Comment: My friend Mr e man!!! I don't know how to thank you! I had not seen that silly mistake ... I really appreacite your help, seriously .. That change solved my problem .... How do I rank your answer as the correct one? this is the first time I use this page ... :) Seriously, thank you! :)

Comment: That's just a comment. I'll make it into an answer, then you can hit the check mark on the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your equations for $a$ and $b$ are wrong. You have

$$a_n=\frac1{T_s}\int_0^{T_s}\sin\frac{\pi x}{T_s}\cos\frac{n\pi x}{T_s}\,dx+\frac1T\int_{T_s}^T0\cos\frac{n\pi x}{T_s}\,dx$$

instead of

$$a_n=\frac2T\int_0^{T_s}\sin\frac{\pi x}{T_s}\cos\frac{2n\pi x}T\,dx+\frac2T\int_{T_s}^T0\cos\frac{2n\pi x}T\,dx.$$

Note that Wolfram uses period $T=2L$, and that the factors of $\cos$ (for $a$, and $\sin$ for $b$) use $T$, not $T_s$.